# Trying to test Flask endpoint. AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I'm trying to test my `Flask` API with `pytest`, but i'm strugling with this error: `AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`. It's being raised when I do a post request to `/authentication/users`. The endpoint works perfectly when I use `Postman` and the `unit tests` im my User model works too (they don't use `client`). Here is my code:

```
# conftest.py

# ... imports here ...

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config.from_object(TestSettings)
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            # starts connection with tests db
            db = MongoEngine(app)

        yield client  # Do the tests

        with app.app_context():
            # drop db after tests
            db.connection.drop_database('test')
```

My test that use `client`

```
# integrations/test_auth_endpoints.py
def test_create_user(client):
    """
    GIVEN the /authentication/users endpoint
    WHEN a POST request is made
    THEN check the status code, message and data of response
    """
    usr_data = {
        "nome": "ana",
        "cpf": "12345678913",
        "email": "ana@gmail.com",
        "password": "my-secret.@"
    }
    req = client.post('/authentication/users', data=usr_data)  # <-- AttributeError here
    assert req.status == 201
```

So what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of debugging. I figured out what I did wrong.
In my settings i have set

```
APPLICATION_ROOT = Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

I wrongly assumed `APPLICATION_ROOT` to be the project root and it was returning a PositionPath object.

Comment: Yeah, it's the URL path part, not the file system path. Flask docs don't explain this setting good IMO.